Some Gnome utils (like eog) start too slow; DBus juggler needed
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 the other day, and experienced some Gnome utils to start slowly. I managed to track it down to some DBus problem, however I'm not a DBus expert and seek for help. The system is hardly modified; its default target is multi-user, and the graphical interface is started by issuing startx after login.
When using the console, eog stalls for a while before displaying anything. The same is true if I try to start Settings from the drop-down menu in the upper right corner. But finally they start, and gsettins does work without an error message.
user@host:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Fuji_san_by_amaral.png'
user@host:~$

There are three dbus-daemons running in the system. If I'm right, one is system-wide, one is the default user-wide, the third is a kind of "accessibility" (whatever its meaning is), also user-wide.
user@host:~$ ps -ef | grep dbus-daemon | grep -v grep
message+     978       1  0 14:28 ?        00:00:01 @dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
user      1612    1579  0 14:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
user      1881    1872  0 14:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_0

In the default case, the DBus communication socket is the following.
user@host:~$ declare | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus

If I change the socket to the accessibility version in a terminal session on the local console, things get the opposite in that session: eog and gnome-control-center start immediately, but gsettings fails with an error.
user@host:~$ export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_0
user@host:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Fuji_san_by_amaral.png'

(process:4612): dconf-WARNING **: 18:02:32.008: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name ca.desrt.dconf was not provided by any .service files
user@host:~$

Since the new scope is valid only in the given terminal session, the delay remains when trying to start Settings using the GUI, but I'm sure the Settings wouldn't be saved (because of the same error as in the case of gsettings) when started by CLI in the modified session.
To complicate things a bit more, if I login via SSH with ssh -Y host, by default the situation is the same as on my local GUI console, i.e. eog and gnome-control-center start with a delay, and gsettings also works. However if I issue an export $(dbus-launch) in the SSH session, the GUI apps will start immediately without any delay, but gsettings remains operational, no error is given. In this case, the session uses a temporary DBus socket.
user@host:~$ declare | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/tmp/dbus-yYHFChlc7G,guid=e45a123680e516202741ecb96659f62b

If anyone is experienced with DBus enough to advise me what to check or reconfigure (and how) so I could use the GUI as expected (without delays and errors without continuously needing to reconfigure the given session I'm using), or why I'm experiencing all this, I'd appreciate it!

I'm not sure if it is an answer, but it seems to be more of an answer than a simple comment.
I set graphical.target back to default, and suddenly everything got fixed. I understand that hardly any people use a desktop OS with a text console, so this feature might not have been tested before releasing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. However, this still seems to be a bug to me. I'm thinking about filing a bug report on this, but I need to check how it can be done, so I may be too lazy to do it. For now I can live with GDM starting upon boot (rather than doing more debugging)...
If anyone has a solution to this problem meantime, please share it here!

https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting read and decide.
